# Paraview not accessible from other accounts

Tags: macos, applications, permission

I'm administering some Mac Minis for our workgroup. I recently needed to install [Paraview](http://paraview.org), but ran into some problems I still couldn't resolve.

When installing Paraview 5.1.2 from it's .dmg file by moving the icon onto the Application folder, it ends up in /Applications. For this installation I used the only local account stsadmin, which surprisingly is an admin account. I can start the application, so everything seems to be fine.
When I log in with another account, which in our case are network accounts, I can't open Paraview.

> You do not have permissions to open the application "paraview".

I then checked the permissions:

```
$ ls -adl /Applications/paraview.app/
drwx------  3 stsadmin  admin  102 Jul 27 02:30 /Applications/paraview.app/
```

When I look at some other apps like VLC, this app belongs to root/wheel instead of stsadmin/admin.

Questions are:

1. Is this problem caused by paraview? Or did I use the wrong installation process?
2. How to fix it? chown? chgrp? If so, what is the correct user/group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with **your** installation method. A lot of apps are intended to be installed by just simply dropping the app on the Applications folder.

Now either the packager/creator of the application bundle in the dmg made a mistake or the permissions of the bundle are deliberate.

To allow other users to use the app, modifying the permissions with the following command should be sufficient:

```
sudo chmod -R u=rwx,go=rx /Applications/paraview.app
```

Comment: Thanks! I was somehow focused on chown and chgrp, that I totally forgot about chmod...